# I am interested in being a front-end developer. Where should I start?

Tags: php, html, css, frontend

Should I first master HTML/CSS/PHP? Is there something else I should learn right away? Also, should I go to college or be self-taught?

Comment: Google is your best friend

Comment: Broad and opinion-based questions do not, unfortunately, fit well on Stack Overflow. Maybe a beginner coder community, like [CodeNewbie](http://codenewbie.org)? They have a very active forum.

Comment: Join one of the local coder clubs, like ladies learning code or javascript night. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

This is primarily opinion based... But just to give my two cents.

HTML/CSS is the best place to start when striving to be a front end developer. Doing HTML/CSS will give you the basic idea of how code works, directory structure, dealing with errors or inaccuracies with grammar and compatibility.

It never, ever hurts to start young. From experience of being in a tech field, people who start young, tend to get jobs more easily. Not only will it help you with getting a job later, but advancing in that field now will help you with going to a University or college for those classes. Typically learning how to code in school with no prior experience, can be slow, frustrating or confusing. Learning how to code now can help you avoid those frustrations with stricter deadlines, and make projects a ton easier and susceptible to be better a problem solver, not to even mention better grades.

A personal recommendation in a order of learning would be:

1. Google
2. HTML
3. CSS
4. JavaScript
5. PHP

As commentated above, Google is your best friend. Learn how to Google efficiently. Once you get the basic of how HTML works, CSS code, how to write basic JavaScript and PHP such as loops, conditionals, error handling, etc. You can start to learn backend technology such as working with databases, OS, bootstrap, ASP, .NET, creating Content Management Systems, etc.

There is a ton of resources you can use online to learn.

- [thenewboston](https://www.thenewboston.com)
- [codeacademy](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC5CMtpogD_P3mOoeiDHD5eQ)
- stackoverflow
- Google

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend starting with something like this:

https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/web

It'll teach you the fundamentals of basic styling (HTML/CSS), the interactive nature of tutorials on Codecademy makes them more enjoyable & engaging than others.

(I'm not affiliated with Codecademy in any way, I just quite like their tutorials).

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you should complete all the basic web technologies from w3schools.com. Once done choose an IDE like webstorm and create a sample website using the HTML CSS JavaScript.

To become front end developer you should become proficient in following technologies:

1.HTML 5
2. CSS 3
3. JavaScript.
4. Jquery
5. Angular JS
6. AJAX
7. Browser compatibility like using bootstrap.
8. Operating system.
9. Node.js 
10. Any backend technology.

Comment: w3schools.com is not the best place to go look for tutorials. They have a history of being rife with inaccuracies. There are so many better options out there today.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean a front end *web* developer.

As such, as many have stated, the web's front end is made up of:

- html
- css
- javascript

That's it. So learn that to start with.

And that point you need to start thinking about what to focus on. Would you prefer to spend more time working with UX and UI teams and becoming more of an interaction designer on the front end, or would you prefer to spend more time working with the back end team and making sure UI and the back end are properly integrated.

If the former, you may want to focus on learning design concepts. Read up on user experience design and interface design. Pick up a couple of graphic design courses.

If the latter, that may lead you more down the path of a computer science degree.